# How to get Contacts in a Table in Android using SQLite?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, datatables, contacts

I want to get the contacts stored on the phone into a table created in my SQLite db.
The columns show the different fields e.g Name, phone number, email etc
and each row shows a different contact.
How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use androids content provider to get contacts data as a cursor and then iterate cursor rows and save data to sqlite

First add permission:-

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" >
</uses-permission>
```

Then in java class:-

```
Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
while (phones.moveToNext())
{
  String name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
  String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

}
phones.close();
```

In while loop add to your sqlite data base

Comment: is there a way to get data directly from ContactsContracts.data?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:-

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "EventBoard.db";
public static final String EVENTS_TABLE = "Events";
public static final String GUESTS_TABLE = "Guests";
public Context ctx;

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
     ctx = context;
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + EVENTS_TABLE + "( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,Name TEXT,Time TEXT,Date TEXT,Venue TEXT,Contact TEXT,Description TEXT);");
    db.execSQL("create table " + GUESTS_TABLE + "(Name TEXT,Phone TEXT,Email TEXT);");
    createGuestsTable(ctx);
}
```

Comment: 'public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // remove title
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        myDb.createGuestsTable(this);
    }'


This is what I did. I called my method in my MainActivity instead of DatabaseHelper class. It worked.. is it good practice?

Comment: Code you are doing is fine. Just to make your code organised it is good practice to make a separate class for your tasks. But as there is only  a small portion of code for database writing, you can continue with one java file also.

Comment: And if you want to have separate file for this then I think my above code should work. The only issue you were facing in null pointer exception was the context. So pass main activities context